# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sum'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize some data using a pie chart in matplotlib.

But I'm getting this type of error and could not fix it.

I tried the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

labels = 'Updated', 'Coverage (overall)', 'last 24 hours', 'Deleted', 'Deleted last 24 hours', 'Banned', 'Banned last 24 hours'
sizes = (6, 5.04, 0, 12, 0, 7, 7)
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey']

def absolute_value(val):
    a  = numpy.round(val/100.*sizes.sum(), 0)
    return a

plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct=absolute_value)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Now the output:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 12
      9     a  = numpy.round(val/100.*sizes.sum(), 0)
     10     return a
---> 12 plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors,
     13         autopct=absolute_value)
     15 plt.axis('equal')
     16 plt.show()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2715, in pie(x, explode, labels, colors, autopct, pctdistance, shadow, labeldistance, startangle, radius, counterclock, wedgeprops, textprops, center, frame, rotatelabels, normalize, data)
   2708 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.pie)
   2709 def pie(
   2710         x, explode=None, labels=None, colors=None, autopct=None,
   (...)
   2713         textprops=None, center=(0, 0), frame=False,
   2714         rotatelabels=False, *, normalize=True, data=None):
-> 2715     return gca().pie(
   2716         x, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
   2717         autopct=autopct, pctdistance=pctdistance, shadow=shadow,
   2718         labeldistance=labeldistance, startangle=startangle,
   2719         radius=radius, counterclock=counterclock,
   2720         wedgeprops=wedgeprops, textprops=textprops, center=center,
   2721         frame=frame, rotatelabels=rotatelabels, normalize=normalize,
   2722         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}))

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1423, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1420 @functools.wraps(func)
   1421 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1422     if data is None:
-> 1423         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1425     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1426     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1427                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:3236, in Axes.pie(self, x, explode, labels, colors, autopct, pctdistance, shadow, labeldistance, startangle, radius, counterclock, wedgeprops, textprops, center, frame, rotatelabels, normalize)
   3234     s = autopct % (100. * frac)
   3235 elif callable(autopct):
-> 3236     s = autopct(100. * frac)
   3237 else:
   3238     raise TypeError(
   3239         'autopct must be callable or a format string')

Cell In[46], line 9, in absolute_value(val)
      8 def absolute_value(val):
----> 9     a  = numpy.round(val/100.*sizes.sum(), 0)
     10     return a

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

I pasted the entire tracecall back hopefully to determine the error perfectly.

How can I fix that?

Comment: `sizes` is a tuple and it doesn't have `sum()` method. What is unclear? what do you want to do with this `100.*sizes.sum()`?

Comment: Try `sum(sizes)`

Comment: I want to display the values inside the pie chart (on it) and the labels outside it. @buran

Comment: Worked! But 5.04 is shown as 5.0. and normal numbers are shown with another zero (5 -> 5.0). How can I just show them as their reality? @Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out This code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

labels = ['Updated', 'Coverage (overall)', 'last 24 hours', 'Deleted', 'Deleted last 24 hours', 'Banned', 'Banned last 24 hours']
sizes = [6, 5.04, 0, 12, 0, 7, 7]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'green', 'black', 'red', 'grey']

def absolute_value(val):
    a  = numpy.round(val/100*sizes.sum(), 0)
    return a

plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

You should use the `sizes` and `colors` as list